# Animation Nodes add-on does not appear after installation

Tags: add-on, animation-nodes

So, I was going to make a clock timer animation where a text object will count up over time. I was planning on achieving this by using the "animation nodes" addon but every time I try to import the addon from the zip file or the master file it does not show up anywhere in the addons window. It has that 'i' message thing in the Info panel saying that it has been added, but I can't find it.

I have also been using blender 2.79 (I know I should be using 2.8+, but I just didn't have time to install it yet)
Do I need 2.8+ to fix this problem? Or is there another solution?

Comment: While not an answer per se, it may help you to look here: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Animation Nodes add-on only works with Blender 2.8x which is documented in the [*Can't install Animation Nodes* issue](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1240).

> **Animation Nodes needs at least Blender 2.80**
>
> The latest version of Animation Nodes only works with Blender 2.80. Install a newer Blender build.